# jQuery code can't access a function of a controller of a component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-components

I am trying to access a function of a controller, which is a part of a an angular component, tried with `angular.element('#elementId').scope().functionName();` 
but didn't work. here is my html template

**customerAddressBook.template.html**

```
<div id='customerAddressBook'>
   <div class="ui equal width segment form" id="addNewCustomerForm">
          <h4 class="ui dividing sub header">Add new customer</h4>
          <div class="eight wide field">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="customer.title" id="title" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="three fields">
            <div class="field">
              <label for="name">Customer name</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="customer.name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label for="gender">Gender</label>
              <select id="gender" ng-model="customer.gender" class="ui dropdown">
                  <option class="default text" value="">Select</option>
                  <option class="item" data-value="male">Male</option>
                  <option class="item" data-value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label for="contact">Customer contact number</label>
              <div class="ui labeled input">
                <div class="ui teal label">
                  +91
                </div>
                <input class="ui input" type="text" ng-model="customer.contact" id="contact" required />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
              <label for="adress">Address</label>
              <textarea cols="8" rows="4" style="resize:none;overflow:auto;" ng-model="customer.address" id="address" required />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label for="landmark">Landmark</label>
              <!-- this field should be conncted to google maps api -->
              <input type="text" ng-model="customer.landmark" id="landmark" placeholder="Nearest landmark" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui divider"></div>
          <button type="button" class="ui right floated submit blue button">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="ui right floated black clear button">Clear</button>
        </div>
 </div>
```

and here is my jQuery code which calls an angular function upon successful validation of the form elements,

```
$('#addNewCustomerForm').form({
        fields: {
          title: 'empty',
          name : 'empty',
          contact: ['minLength[10]','empty'],
          gender: 'empty',
          address: 'empty',
          landmark: 'empty'
        },
        onSuccess: function(){
          angular.element('#customerAddressBook').$ctrl.getValues();
        }
      });
```

and finally here is my angular code :

**customerAddressBook.component.js :**

```
    angular.module('customerAddressBook', []);

    angular.module('customerAddressBook').component('customerAddressBook', {
      templateUrl: 'customerAddressBook.template.html',
      controller: function() {
        this.getValues = function(){
          console.log($ctrl.customer);
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: There is no element with the id `elementId` and there is no function on $scope with the name `functionName`. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @amitwadhwani I want to call a function which is inside the controller from my jQuery code, and I want to know how I can do that

Comment: @georgeawg ignore the html template, have a look at the angular code which has a function called **getValues()** , and I want to call that function from my jQuery code and I want to know how I can achieve that.